# How to start Second Activity when ad is closed? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, ads

In my app, the user starts in the MainActivity. When the button (btn) is clicked, an interstitial ad pops up. I want it to go to the SecondActivity when the ad is closed, but it just goes back to MainActivity. I've pasted my code below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
val i:Intent = Intent(this, SecoundActivity::class.java)


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
    var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

    InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
            mInterstitialAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {

            mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object:FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    startActivity(i)
                }
            }
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }
    })

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd?.show(this)

        }
    }
}
```

}

Any way to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `mInterstitialAd` is nullable, your `FullScreenContentCallback` is never going to be initialized, because  `mInterstitialAd` is null when you're trying to invoke it. It will be executed before `onAdLoaded` will be called.

Put the full screen content callback in the onAdLoaded callback like this

```
    override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
        interstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = object:FullScreenContentCallback() {
            override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                startActivity(i)
            }
        }
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd  
    }
```

Also it is best practice to put variable initialization to the top of the class instead of the bottom

```
private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
private val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
```

Comment: I added your code to the activity. However, the app still redirects back to MainActivity when the ad is closed. The updated code is in the question.

Comment: You didn't add my exact code. Check again. Replace mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback
with
interstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback
your mInterstitialAd is still null, because you assign it afterwards ..